# Good class design: dependency vs duplication?

Tags: design, class, dependencies

Let's say we have a class( My_Func_Dec ) that models a 'function header declaration' as it might appear in a .h file.

```
const std::string func1 ( const std::string& arg1_, const std::string& arg2_ ) const ;
```

[image: Overview!]

As we might guess from the pic(see above), My_Func_Dec initializes its internal data by processing(left-->right) a string to extract the various components of the 'function header declaration'.

Despite the beg of the 'return type' being relatively easy to find, there is still some work to do in isolating the whole return type(See below).

[image]

My question is when it comes to My_Func_Dec::get_name whose main purpose is to isolate the func name.  In terms of good code design, should it be:

Bearing in mind the string is being processed left to right,

a) Call My_Func_Dec::get_rtype to set the start position(See below).  Which avoids code duplication.

or

b) Copy and paste the code from My_Func_Dec::get_rtype to set the start position.  Which lowers dependency.

Consider if we go with b) then My_Func_Dec::get_semicolon is going to be quite a long function.

[image]

Please don't get distracted by the example code.  This is primarily a question about code duplication, dependency, and encapsulation in the context of class member functions.

Comment: Extract the shared part from `get_rtype` into a private helper function (perhaps parameterized to make it slightly more general), then reuse the new function in both `get_rtype` and `get_name`. You'll avoid code duplication, you'll also make the code in `get_rtype` and `get_name` *simpler*. The dependency is not really a problem - since this is internal to each function, and since the helper function is private, you can always change the the code within a particular public function to use something else if the need arises.

Comment: Your example would typically be done by a parser, which would avoid duplicate work by keeping a position in the input. Object oriented or procedural parsers would keep that position in a slot or variable, while a parser written in a functional language would return it together with the parsed thing. So one possible approach to avoiding duplicate work is to remember how far you got already. For other cases, other approaches might fit better, of course.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Youre describing exactly how the 'function header declaration' is parsed in the class body before being passed as args to My_Func_Dec ctor.  Some back and forth on which object should be responsible for parsing.  In the end I landed on two, 1)Internal to My_Func_Dec init 2) Any caller of My_Func_Dec ctor.  It's double parsing but keeps both sides honest.  On reflection, no reason to change this idiom when parsing within My_Func_Dec as the complexity is the same. An added bonus is the parsing func( for each component ) being fully encapsulated.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović The 'shared part' is really the whole code from get_rtype, because in order to get_name you first need to get_rtype.  I tried hard to create a generalised func which took an arg and returned the desired header component, but due to subtle differences in the context of each component it meant a series of checks and code blocks + any duplicate code was too few to justify the extra complexity caused by delegating to other functions.  It made for cleaner and more understandable code to have a single encapsulated custom func for each header component.

Answer (score 2):

You've completely omitted the third (and preferable) approach:

1. call `My_Func_Dec::get_rtype` - avoids duplication, increases coupling
2. copy the code from `My_Func_Dec::get_rtype` - increases duplication, reduces coupling
3. abstract out the common code into a shared utility which, in deference to normal C++ terminology, I'll call a *tokenizer* ([phase 7](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) if we ignore preprocessing)

   - No duplication
   - No coupling between peers

     (use of a lower-level utility is not generally regarded as coupling to be avoided, or you'd be trying to avoid `std::string` in the first place)

Comment: Filip Milovanović suggested something similar. In a nutshell the subtle differences in the context of each component token means its hard to justify the extra coupling and complexity that a generic utility func would bring.  ps.. there is big difference between coupling custom code to std( which is unavoidable if you want to write good code and might even be considered best practice) and the coupling between two custom code blocks.

Comment: There's a big difference between peer-level coupling and dependency on _any_ lower layer - not only on the standard library. And whatever those subtle differences are, if they're relevant to determining a suitable answer, they should be in the question - as text.